# Docker image created date is displaying incorrectly

Tags: docker

I am relatively new to Docker and have noticed a strange issue with the images I am creating.

My very simple Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:5.4-apache
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data src /var/www/html
COPY php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

After I build the image and use the 'docker image ls' command I get the following output.

```
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
xxxxx/dcalc             latest    ea718faxxxxx   6 years ago    477MB
```

I don't understand why the CREATED date is showing 6 years ago. I get that the base image (referred to in the FROM command) is that old, but shouldn't my image which has a COPY command in it create a new image with a current created date?

If this is expected behaviour can somebody explain why it is correct?

EDIT: I am on MacOS using Docker Desktop, but its the same behaviour on Linux (Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701).

Thanks.

Comment: Windows or linux?

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34786

Comment: check image: `docker image inspect [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]`and maybe also check the container logs `docker logs <container>`

Comment: Please include the full build command and it's output.

Comment: Is this still true? I couldn't reproduce in `20.10.21`. On the other hand, I can reproduce without the `COPY` commands, due to the issue @NikolaiShevchenko links.

Answer (score 0):

I just set up Docker for the first time and had the same question, that's how I came across your thread. I realized that in my case -- and this might not apply to you -- the images in question were generated by external sources, so the created dates are presumably based on their original creation date or a later modification date by the source, not the date they're created on my computer. One was a welcome-to-docker image generated by Docker, and the other was a Vikunja image. The date for any container that I create myself is generating correctly.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to get rid of this file modified date issue is to set timezone for linux instance

in Dockerfile

```
RUN rm /etc/localtime
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Istanbul /etc/localtime
```

Change your timezone and find it from /usr/share/zoneinfo/* for your timezone.

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

timezone of you and docker instance is now the same.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that timezones explain a 6 year discrepancy.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to check the date of docker image which is created on your system, you can use:-

```
docker ps -a
```

`docker images` command shows the date which the image is created.